# Disabling the windows that occurs when shutting down or restarting MacBook - User can't log off from Mac without admin rights

Tags: macbook-pro, mac

We have a Macbook Air on our office and multiple users use it every day. Shutting down or restarting has now caused this alert dialog window to appear, which says:

> Restarting may cause other users logged into this computer to lose unsaved changes. to avoid losing unsaved changes, log out of all users before restarting. to continue without saving changes, enter an admin name and password and then click restart.

How can I disable that dialog window from occuring? It hasn't showed up before and it occurs now after the OS was updated.

Comment: You can‘t disable it. See the answer below for the reason it is shown.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a new thing at all.
If other users are logged in then this has been the warning since at least Snow Leopard [2009] & probably long before. Users need to log themselves out correctly after use; if not, then an admin is needed to override that.

Comment: I'd wager it's been in OS X since multiple users logged in was possible; which may have been day 1.

Comment: @benwiggy - probably right. I've now tracked it back as far as Snow Leopard ;))

Comment: @Tetsujin, so do you know how to override this as admin?

Comment: You fill in admin credentials in the dialog box. Only an admin is deemed to have the authority to discard other users' data without saving.

Comment: @tetsujin Thank you! So there is no possibility to disable that window for permanently?

Comment: No, it's a system warning; potential loss of data. You need to either get an admin to shutdown or train the other users to log out when they've finished.

Comment: @tetsujin Ok, thank you very much!